# Wordpress : Page that can be viewed only by members and if not a member than show them a registration page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, membership, user-registration

I am trying to create a sampling process , where a user need to register or login to view my sample pdf documents , and once they register the user should be given a role as a sampler .

I am not a pro at wordpress but am learning . Can u guys suggest me some plugin or ideas on how to do it , i am using wordpress WordPress 3.3.1 .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form

As per your latest question, you will need to use these in tandem with each other, and make sure to define your redirect within your argument array to make sure the user is directed back to the page from which they logged in.

**FINAL UPDATE:** Enter this in your functions.php file and utilize as you see fit. This will allow you to output information according to the actual role of your user. This is also assuming that your plugin is creating actual custom roles. If not, you will have to utilize the [Add Role Function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role):

```
function get_user_role()
{
    global $current_user;

    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

    return $user_role;
}
```

Then in the template of the page you want:

```
<?php
if(is_user_logged_in())
{
    switch(get_user_role())
    {
        case 'customer' :
            //CUSTOMER DISPLAY
        break;
        case 'subscriber' :
            //SUBSCRIBER DISPLAY
        break;
        default :
            //OTHER TYPE OF USER DISPLAY
    }
}
else
{
    //NO LOGGED USER DISPLAY
}
?>
```

Comment: That should work fine , but i also want a way by which user can register as subscriber  or login and then go back to the same page .

Comment: Review the edits. Those two functions should take care of everything you're looking for.

Comment: This will also help give you a step in the right direction with registration: http://www.tutorialstag.com/create-custom-wordpress-registration-page.html

Comment: Hey maiorano84 , thanks i think i am closer but let me describe u in more detail and hope u can help . I have two kinds of user in my website one would be like wordpress users with role as subscribers and other are wordpress users with custom roles like customers created by my woocommerce cart, I want to create a page which only my users can see and if they are not users they can register it , but if they are already a wordpress user with custom role like customer no need for them to register

Comment: I tried wishlist membership plugin , it does all the things like content control and registration and login redirection , but it shows my customers as non members as it does not automatically add them to any membership level . What i need is some suggestion in a sense of plugin thats mix of theme my login and role scoper and if that does not work i would have to write on my own based on links u gave

Comment: What you're asking for now certainly wasn't in the original question. Please review my latest update, and if it helps, please mark as answered. If you have additional questions later, please create a new question and I will be sure to help you.